# Can I use "who" in "name someone (who) you'd hate to see show up"

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning, gerunds, infinitives

"Name someone you'd hate to see show up?" can I use "who" For example "Name someone *who* you'd hate to see show up?"

Comment: You've got two unrelated questions here - can you please make this more focused?

Comment: Welcome to ELL!  Please edit your enquiry to remove the second question. You can still ask both but they need to be separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first question, you would need to use *whom* because where you are placing in in the sentence makes it a direct object.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/who-vs-whom-grammar-usage

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  The following are synonymous:

- Name someone you'd like to see show up.
- Name someone that you'd like to see show up. (Some people prefer to avoid using "that" for human referents.)
- Name someone who you'd like to see show up.
- Name someone whom you would like to see show up.  (Very formal.)

Note: the OP edited their question to make it more focused.  The remainder of this answer is only relevant to the original question.

Modal verbs, too, are followed by infinitives - it's just that they are bare infinitives.

Most non-modals that take infinitives take full ("to") infinitives, but there are a few exceptions that take bare infinitives:

- I made him do it.
- I saw/watched/heard him do it.

In the case of saw/watched/heard, the *-ing* form works too:

- I saw him doing it.

"Name someone you'd like to see showing up" sounds odd, though.  It may be because showing up is typically conceived as an event rather than an action with a duration.

Comment: Your example #3 is not correct in "proper" English, though it is common in speech and even writing depending on the tone of the work. Example #4 is correct. See FelinusRex' answer: *who* is the form used if the word is the subject of a sentence, while *whom* is the form used if the word is any other part of a sentence.

Comment: That's a matter of opinion.  It depends how much of a prescriptivist you are.  But certainly, if the situation is informal enough that you're happy to use the contraction "you'd" (as in the example sentence), it's also informal enough to use "who" here.  Indeed, using "whom" and "you'd" together is unusual.

Comment: A fair point. I guess I would be more likely to say either #1 or #4 and not #2 or #3, myself.